# Keyboard and mouse is not working properly

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I am having some weired problem regarding mouse and keyboard. I am using a laptor with a external mouse. When i scroll my mouse it worked in reverse way. And when i am typing with my keyboard it stop working for few moment. If i typed two later repeatedly it missed to draw the 2nd letter. Backspace is not working properly either. It need 4 stock to remove a letter. Help please

Answer (score 0):

Salam. Go to all settings and see carefully all and their tabs. I think it was a choice in "universal access" tabs same as "stop mouse when i use keyboard". I unchecked this before, but I forgot where it was. excuse me.